# Spark: how to set worker-specific SPARK_HOME in standalone mode

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-spark

I'm setting up a [somewhat ad-hoc] cluster of Spark workers: namely, a couple of lab machines that I have sitting around. However, I've run into a problem when I attempt to start the cluster with `start-all.sh`: namely, Spark is installed in different directories on the various workers. But the master invokes `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh` on each one using the **master's** definition of `$SPARK_HOME`, even though the path is different for each worker.

Assuming I can't install Spark on identical paths on each worker to the master, how can I get the master to recognize the different worker paths?

**EDIT #1** Hmm, found [this thread in the Spark mailing list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Cluster-launch-td1484.html), strongly suggesting that this is the current implementation--assuming `$SPARK_HOME` is the same for all workers.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my reply to this mailing list thread? I have  a question about a configuring different `log4j.properties` per worker that I can't seem to overcome. This isn't what I'd use in reality, but for mucking around and understanding what's going on it would be of help

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing around with Spark on Windows (my laptop) and have two worker nodes running by starting them manually using a script that contains the following

```
set SPARK_HOME=C:\dev\programs\spark-1.2.0-worker1
set SPARK_MASTER_IP=master.brad.com 
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master.brad.com:7077
```

I then create a copy of this script with a different SPARK_HOME defined to run my second worker from. When I kick off a spark-submit I see this on `Worker_1`

```
15/02/13 16:42:10 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: ...C:\dev\programs\spark-1.2.0-worker1\bin...
```

and this on `Worker_2`

```
15/02/13 16:42:10 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: ...C:\dev\programs\spark-1.2.0-worker2\bin...
```

So it works, and in my case I duplicated the spark installation directory, but you may be able to get around this

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider assign the name by changing `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` line in the `spark-env.sh` file.

Comment: This did not seem to make a difference in my experiments

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44091152/194872)

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74257968/194872) I used was to create a symbolic link mimicking the master node's installation path on each worker node so when the `start-all.sh` executing on the master node does its SSH into the worker node, it will see identical pathing to run the worker scripts.

Example in my case, I had 2 Macs and 1 Linux machine. Both Macs had spark installed under `/Users/<user>/spark` however the Linux machine had it under `/home/<user>/spark`. One of the Macs was the master node so running the `start-all.sh` it would error each time on the Linux machine due to pathing (`error: /Users/<user>/spark does not exist`)).

The simple solution was to mimic the Mac's pathing on the Linux machine using a symbolic link:

open terminal

`cd /` <-- go to the root of the drive

`sudo ln -s home Users` <-- create a sym link "Users" pointing to the actual "home" directory.