# How to use start-all.sh to start standalone Worker that uses different SPARK_HOME (than Master)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I have installed spark 2.1.1 on 2 machines but in **different relative locations** ie in one machine I have installed somewhere on an NTFS drive and on the other one I have installed it on an ext4 drive. I am trying to start a cluster in **standalone mode** with 2 slaves and a master by having 1 Master and 1 slave on 1 machine and 1 slave on other machine.

When I try to start this cluster via `start-all.sh` script on master node, I get the following error :-

```
192.168.1.154: bash: line 0: cd: /home/<somePath>/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7: No such file or directory
```

I have set proper `SPARK_HOME` in respective `bashrc` files. Below is my *slave* file (in the 1 master + 1 slave machine)

```
localhost
192.168.1.154
```

I can remotely login to the 1 slave machine via ssh. I am able to run Spark cluster individually in each machine.

It is my understanding when I try to remotely start a slave from my master machine via `start-all.sh` script it is trying to goto the location where spark is installed on master node, but as on slave node the spark is installed on a different location, it fails. Can anyone please tell me how can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [start-all.sh](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sbin/start-all.sh) you can find the following:

```
if [ -z "${SPARK_HOME}" ]; then
  export SPARK_HOME="$(cd "`dirname "$0"`"/..; pwd)"
fi

# Load the Spark configuration
. "${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/spark-config.sh"

# Start Master
"${SPARK_HOME}/sbin"/start-master.sh

# Start Workers
"${SPARK_HOME}/sbin"/start-slaves.sh
```

which has nothing to do with the Spark installation on the standalone master. `start-all.sh` simply uses whatever `SPARK_HOME` you've defined globally and uses it across all nodes in the cluster, for standalone master and workers.

In your case, I'd recommend writing a custom startup script that would start the standalone Master and workers per respective `SPARK_HOME` env vars.

`start-slaves.sh` (source [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sbin/start-slaves.sh)) does simply the following:

```
cd "${SPARK_HOME}" \; "${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-slave.sh" "spark://$SPARK_MASTER_HOST:$SPARK_MASTER_PORT"
```

And so there is not much magic going on, but to `ssh` to every node and execute the command line.

---

I *think* I'd even use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your ~/.bashr. You can see my bashrc below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.12.1
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark/2.1.0
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
```

Finally, you have to update your bashrc environment:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you your response. But I don't it's strictly relevant to my question. Anyways SPARK_HOME is set properly on both the machines

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 Macs and 1 PC/Linux machine as workers. 1 of the Macs acted as a master as well.

On the Macs, I had installed spark under `/Users/<user>/spark` and set my $SPARK_HOME to this path.

On the Linux machine (ubuntu), I had setup the spark directory under `/home/<user>/spark`. When running `start-all.sh` on my spark master machine (1 of the Macs) would cause an error on the Linux worker:
`192.168.1.33: bash: line 1: cd: /Users/<user>/spark: No such file or directory 192.168.1.33: bash: line 1: /Users/<user>/spark/sbin/start-worker.sh: No such file or directory`

In order to fix the pathing problem, I mimicked the Mac by creating a symbolic link on the Linux machine pointing a "/Users" directory to the "/home" directory. This tricked Spark into working on that Linux machine/worker just as it works on the Macs

`cd /`

`sudo ln -s home Users`

This is probably not the most elegant solution but it meant I did not need to maintain my own version of `start-all.sh` and its associated subscripts.